# Can formly form input and label be swapped around?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-formly

I want to target formly form's label when input is in focus but because formly form generates the label first I can't use the sibling selector `.form-control + label`.

Is there a way to swap them so that we get something like

```
<div>
  <input class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty ng-valid-maxlength"
         ng-model="model[options.key]" id="vm.form_input_vehicleRegistration_0" 
         name="vm.form_input_vehicleRegistration_0" formly-custom-validation="" 
         maxlength="20" type="text">
  <label for="vm.form_input_vehicleRegistration_0" class="control-label " ng-if="to.label">
    Registration
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can write custom input control

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FieldType } from '@ngx-formly/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'formly-field-input',
 template: `
   <div>
  <input class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty ng-valid-maxlength"
         ng-model="model[options.key]" id="vm.form_input_vehicleRegistration_0" 
         name="vm.form_input_vehicleRegistration_0" formly-custom-validation="" 
         maxlength="20" type="text">
  <label for="vm.form_input_vehicleRegistration_0" class="control-label " ng-if="to.label">
    Registration
  </label>
</div>
 `,
})
export class FormlyFieldInput extends FieldType {}
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-formly-custom-template-pmmyfd?file=app/formly-field-input.ts)